# Search Criteria and note in posting for "(us) citizen only"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

I don't know how much this is relevant to other countries and how much this is a problem in other areas in the USA, but in the Washington DC area there are a large number of jobs that are "US citizens only".
This is usually noted in free text in the description. It would be great to have this as a label and searchable/excludable similar to "Visa sponsor". Or would a tag be the correct solution?

`[edit]`
What I am trying to achieve is being able to exclude jobs that are not applicable for me, similar to geographic region or technology, right now I have to check every jobs description whether it is us citizens only or not.

Comment: That probably ought to be one of the lowest levels on a scale of "security clearance required"

Comment: It's not always security related, it might just be a contract requirement when dealing with government agencies. Government grants for example are sometimes limited with regard to using foreign nationals (independent of security)

Comment: It can also be a logistical limitation. Hiring a foreign employee is often more complicated, and some employers may not want to go through the hassle. Some countries may also require that an employer exhaust all local options before hiring abroad.

Comment: The search term to add would be "U.S. person" rather than citizen.  U.S. person includes both citizens and permanent residents.

Comment: @duskwuff there's already a flag for *those* limitations, though - "Visa sponsor". If you don't have the right to work in the target country, the job is not remote, and you don't see the "Visa sponsor" flag, you probably won't be able to get the job. The "US citizen" requirement seems to explicitly exclude people who have the right to work in the US, but are not citizens, like Green Card holders and such.

Comment: If it is to be expandable, it could be similar to the question tag system, where the company advertising could add requirement-tags. Obviously, such a pool of requirement-tags should be separate from SO question tags. What should be implemented will depend on what the desire is for the system. It could be hard-coded flags, which would have to be updated whenever a new requirement came along, or it could be a tag-like system, which would have its own maintenance issues, etc. Overall, it is a good idea for job seekers to be able to filter out job search results for which they *can't* qualify.

Comment: This comes up not just in government work but also in manufacturing; providing access to technical data is considering "exporting" that data and thus legally restricted by regulations such as [ITAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Traffic_in_Arms_Regulations) and [EAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_Administration_Regulations).

Comment: @indiv and Pekka: except as noted by the OP, there are actually jobs that exclude even people with the legal right to work in the U.S. ("Green Card" holders) but who are not yet citizens. See [Executive Order 11935](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/?pid=23665) for an example of one class of jobs.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! We don't have plans to work on this, and I'm not sure where this level of granularity will fit in with our product as we continue to grow (as Pekka noted below, this brings up a bigger question of state-to-state or unique country requirements).

Answer (score 3):

Following from duskwuff's comment above.  This is a common requirement for Government positions, especially Defense jobs.  And it isn't US specific, so we should have a solution that is not US specific.

Perhaps the best solution is to use a `citizen` tag.  This would mean having to be a citizen of the country where the job is posted.  That should make it easy to exclude positions that you aren't able to apply for.

The only downside I can think of is that there are sometimes requirements that a person be an EU citizen.  Now a job posted in France with the `citizen` tag is ambiguous: is that a French citizen or an EU citizen (and you'll have to read the job to know).

Comment: I'd be perfectly fine with this ... how does this work for feature requests or does it stay open for discussion until the powers that be look at it ?

Comment: probably a feature request, but you might want to wait and see if more people up vote this answer: it doesn't seem exactly popular at the moment, so I don't know how much traction it would get as a feature request.

Answer (score -2):

As Ben insinuates, this requirement is possibly government agencies requiring some level of security clearance that is available only to citizens.

As Careers grows globally, it seems unsustainable to create a *specific* label for this: at the end of the day, you'd likely end up with dozens of such labels, satisfying different needs and requirements from state to state and country to country.

Perhaps a generic "special limitations" label might make sense, denoting requirements that aren't specifically linked to the skills asked for in the advert? That *might* help when searching in specific areas, or industries, where the "special requirement" is very likely to mean one common thing (like citizenship/security clearance when searching around D.C., or generally for government jobs in any country).

Comment: A generic label is almost as useless as no label if you don't know what the generic "special limitations" are, if you are searching for a job and this comes up it gives you no information what the actual limitations are, assuming that for the US it is citizens only would just be an assumption

Comment: What makes you think this would be unsustainable? "Must be a citizen of $this_country" is a very common hiring restriction. It's not US-specific -- I've seen it for other countries as well -- and I've almost never seen it as a requirement for a specific state. (Especially since US states don't technically have _citizens_; they simply have _residents_.)

Comment: @duskwuff I would imagine there's a million potential *other* flags apart from "must be citizen/resident of x" that would all need to be implemented... but maybe that's not really the case.

Comment: The "citizen requirement" would cover a large chunk of jobs.  Other special requirements may exist: but as identified could be hard coded *later* as identified.  While "US Citizen" special requirement is a bit US centric, if it is among the most common such requirements currently, implementing it specifically might be worth it.  Perfection is the enemy of the good.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, coming around to agreeing. This is probably a relatively unique requirement... at least there's not millions others waiting around the corner.

Comment: I suspect that in reality we only have one requirement here, not 200: "must be a citizen of the country where the employer is located".

Comment: @MSalters, I think it's more like the opposite: 'job must be in the country where the applicant is located'. I work for a U.S. company but I'm located in the Netherlands (as was necessary for the job I applied for). Still, it would be a useful label.

Comment: There's something ironic about Jobs listed on Stack Overflow that Jon Skeet could not apply for